# YSlow is not at all working with Firebug 2.0.9

Tags: firefox, firebug, mozilla, yslow

I just installed [YSlow](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/yslow/) but only to found that only a basic pages gets created - if I try to click any link on the same YSlow report - no action happens

FireFox - 37.0.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

YSlow development is [abandoned for a long time](https://github.com/marcelduran/yslow/commits/master) now by its original developer.
Though [in January this year there was a post](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/firebug-working-group/MUMPXSkCo_c/discussion) regarding the most used Firebug 2 extensions including YSlow.

The intent behind that post was to identify the extensions, which should be reimplemented by the Firebug Working Group in the future.